# Marlin firmware question for dual extruder

Tags: marlin, extruder

I've recently added a second hotend and extruder assembly to my 3D printer and I've made all the necessary changes in the firmware. I've defined the temp sensor for hotend 2, all the pins for heat and temp as well as defined extruders as 2 instead of 1.

The problem is that the printer display in the motion menu is showing

- Extruder
- Extruder E1
- Extruder E2

"Extruder" and "Extruder E1" both control the primary extruder and "Extruder 2" controls the second extruder.

Any tips, ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about, this is a [feature not a bug](http://marlinfw.org/docs/features/lcd_menu.html).

`Extruder` refers to the active extruder, the [loaded/active tool](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#T:_Select_Tool). Based on the active extruder the `Extruder` controls either your `Extruder E1` (this is known in the firmware as `Extruder E0`!) or your `Extruder E2` (the `Extruder E1` from the firmware).